# How to disable mouse click when progress-bar is loading?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In my angular app, I want to disable any external events like `click` when my progress-bar loads.

Code for load progress-bar:

```
 .config(['cfpLoadingBarProvider', function (cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = true;
    cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = true;
  }])
```

How I can do this?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: check is !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am considering here a button disable after click..

```
function myCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.disable=false;

   $scope.btnClick=function(){
       $scope.disable=true;

       $http.post('apiURL').then(function(response){
         if( response!=null && response.data.error != null){
             //error
             alert('Error');
             $scope.disable=false;
         }else{
             //success
             $scope.data=response.data; 
             $scope.disable=false;
         }
    });
   };
}

<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button ng-disabled="disable==true" ng-click="btnClick()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

From this example you'll get some idea of disabling items..

Comment: is it compulsory to write `ng-disabled="disable==true"`   in button tag??

Comment: No. but it you want to disable button u have to use ng-disabled.